# Как уменьшить размер android приложения?

Tags: android, apk

Есть простое android приложение. На первом устройстве под шестым андроидом приложение занимает чуть больше полутора мб. На другом устройстве под управлением android 7.0 приложение занимает 5,5(!) мб. При том что в google play я видел похожие приложения, которые занимали всего 200 кб. В приложении используется библиотека `GraphView`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как уменьшить размер android приложения.

Comment: Вот статейка из офф документации, может сгодится https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

Comment: Можете добавить в файл gradle.properties эту строчку android.enableD8=true. Статья https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html

Comment: @Whaletail, теперь приложение весит 4,5мб.